Terraform provider: how does one make drift in computed value trigger update?
I am building a terraform provider right now that roughly works as follows:
Background
Inputs:

name
keepers (arbitrary map)
some_attribute (a string)

Calculated attributes

version

How it should work

Takes inputs and internally calculates a value
Stores that value in a remote location identified uniquely by the "name" field. The "name" storage location is created as part of the "create" step.
Upon storing in "name" location, the remote server returns a "version" string.
Reading from "name" always returns the most recent "version".
Does not store the calculated value in state file, instead just stores the "version" as a calculated value.
If the "name" input changes, resource is recreated. (Resource recreation means that the remote server will completely remove the "name" storage, recalculate the value, create a new "name" storage location and store the value there, generating a new "version" as well)
If "keepers" or "some_attribute" changes, resource is updated in place. (In-place update means the value is recalculated and stored under a new "version" at the existing "name" location)
Drift may occur if someone created a new "version" at the "name" location externally. When terraform does a read on "name" it will therefore receive a "version" that differs from what is in the plan. In this circumstance I want to also trigger an in-place update.

Concrete question
Points 1. to 7. above all work as intended, but I am not able to get 8. to work. I had assumed that the way to do this would be to in the Read step set "version" in the state to the "drifted" one, so that terraform wil recognise that an update needs to happen. It does detect the drift, but then instead of triggering an update, it changes the version that is currently in the state to the "drifted" one (I supposed because it views this as the new calculation that it should use).  How do I do this correctly?
Here is my schema:
func (r *someResource) Schema(ctx context.Context, req resource.SchemaRequest, resp *resource.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            "keepers": schema.MapAttribute{
                ElementType: types.StringType,
                Optional:    true,
            },
            "some_attribute": schema.StringAttribute{
                Optional:    true,
            },
            "version": schema.StringAttribute{
                Computed:    true,
            },
            "name": schema.StringAttribute{
                Required:    true,
                PlanModifiers: []planmodifier.String{
                    stringplanmodifier.RequiresReplace(),
                },
            },
        },
    }
}

Here is my "Read" function
func (r *someResource) Read(ctx context.Context, req resource.ReadRequest, resp *resource.ReadResponse) {

    var state someModelV0
    diags := req.State.Get(ctx, &state)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    // Get most recent version number from remote storage
    version, err := remote.GetVersion(context.Background(), r.client, state.Name.ValueString())
    if err != nil {
        resp.Diagnostics.AddError("Read error")     )
        return
    }

    // Update the version in the state so that we know that drift has occured
    state.Version = types.StringValue(version)

    diags = resp.State.Set(ctx, state)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }
}


What you describe sounds like intended and correct behavior for the plugin framework. A parameter value changed externally, and the state is correspondingly updated during Read. Also your displayed code literally causes this behavior. However, your question may actually be asking how to trigger an Update so that the version is reverted to the value in the config. Is that what you are asking?

I don't want to revert to the previous version, I want to trigger an Ùpdate. For everything that is not a computed value, changes to the state that is picked up by Read will automatically cause an update to happen. This make sense if you think about it, since Plan no longer equals State, terraform must update; it doesn't matter that it was the State that changed and not the Plan, the result is an Update.

The planning phase of Terraform performs the following two steps for each resource instance:

"Refreshing": reconcile the Terraform state with the current state of the remote object. This is where Terraform can detect changes made outside of Terraform.
"Planning": compare the refreshed state to the desired state (described by the configuration), and if they differ propose a change that would make the remote object match the desired state. This is where Terraform can react to changes made outside of Terraform, and propose to undo them if the configuration disagrees.

Because version is an attribute whose value is defined by the provider itself rather than a value taken from the desired state, the second step does not apply to that attribute. Terraform only detects change to such an attribute, but does not typically react to it, unless the value of that attribute is used to decide an argument for some other resource. (In which case the update or replace action would be for the instances of that downstream resource, not for your resource type.)
Since Terraform uses planning only to react to differences between the actual state and the desired state, and because there is no "desired state" for the version attribute, there is no reason to propose an "update" for a change to the version attribute alone: it would not change anything about the remote object. Therefore I think your stated goal doesn't seem to make sense for how Terraform works.

Although I don't really understand why such a thing would be needed, you could potentially model this in Terraform (at the expense of a slightly strange user experience) using the following strategy:

Include two attributes in your resource schema. The first tracks the version most recently seen in the remote system, while the second tracks the version your provider most recently returned.
For the sake of the rest of this I'm going to call these current_version and set_version respectively, but the specific names are not important for what I'm describing.

In your provider's "apply" actions (create or update), write the same value into both current_version and set_version, because at that point the provider presumably knows that it has just changed the version and so the two should match.

In your provider's "read" implementation, update current_version to match the value in the remote system.

In the plan phase (using a custom plan modifier), compare the current_version and set_version attribute values. If they differ, return a planned new value where set_version is changed to match current_version. Terraform Core will then interpret this as an "update", and the UI will show that the set_version attribute is changing.


This design would be highly unusual compared to most Terraform providers, so if you implement something like this I would suggest describing the behavior carefully and clearly in your provider documentation, so that operators who are familiar with typical Terraform providers will know to expect this unusual behavior and will hopefully not be so alarmed by it.

Interesting suggestion. Since people reading this question seem puzzled about why anyone would want to do this, let me clarify what I am trying to achieve. I am building a provider that will generate random values to be used as credentials. A lot of people use resources such as random_password or tls_private_key, mistakenly thinking that they are secure, while the generated values end up exposed in the state file. What I am working on is something that will generate values and store them in a remote location (vault), storing only their handle ("name" and "version") in the state file.

The reason for wanting to trigger an Update is to prevent drifts without the user knowing about it. If a vault secret is updated it gets a new version number (that at least is how it works for AKV), but the secret is typically accessed by applications on its "name". So we need a way to trigger an Update so that terraform can reinstate the state as it was in case of drift. In the case of AKVs that actually means copying the contents of the old version and pasting into a new version. (Even just regenerating the credentials and creating a new untampered-with version would be good enough for us)

For now I've solved this by piggy-backing on the "keepers" map. In the "Read" function I do a compare between plan.Version and the latest version on the secret. If there is a difference, I generate a guid and then set a keeper input like {"drift-detected": } on the state. This will generate a plan where terraform wants to remove that entry from the "keepers" map, which triggers an update. It is still strange behaviour, but at least it will only happen rarely (if there is a drift) and it will not actually have any impact other than causing Update to trigger.
